# How to make my Angular default route with submodules work?

Tags: angular

I have the following code:

```
//app-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',    
    children: [
      {
        path: 'admin',
        loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)
      }
    ]
  }
];

//admin-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
 {
   path: '',
   component: ProviderAdminComponent,
   children: [
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'dashboard/default',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
      path: 'dashboard',
      loadChildren: () => import('./theme/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
    }
  ]
},

//dashboard-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    data: {
      title: 'Dashboard',
      status: false
    },
    children: [
     {
        path: 'default',
        loadChildren: () => import('./default/default.module').then(m => m.DefaultModule)
     }
    ]
  }
 ];

//default-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DefaultComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Default Dashboard',
      status: true
    }
  }
];
```

The route: /admin/dashboard/default works, but the route /admin doesn't work.
The /admin route should redirect to /admin/dashboard/default however that doesn't happen.
I get a vague almost white page.
Can anyone tell me why this is happening ?

Comment: Looks like you've defined a component ProviderAdminComponent for the admin/ route. Is that what is being displayed?

Comment: No, it's a page with some almost pure white content. I can vaguely see some background that is orange (almost white). This happens only when doing /admin. But the ProviderAdminComponent is working fine since the route /admin/dashboard/default works fine.

Comment: To be more clear when doing /admin I get the same almost white page like when doing localhost:port/. So it's my app's default page. But the problem is with the route redirect as I said.

Comment: If I add {  path: '', redirectTo: 'default', pathMatch: 'full'  }, in dashboard-routing.module.ts the route /admin/dashboard redirects successfully to /admin/dashboard/default. Howeve the /admin redirect is still not working. Not sure why.

Comment: Have you set enableTracing: true in your router? Might give you a better idea of why the path isn't being matched

Comment: I set enableTracing: true, I also did router.events.subscribe(console.log) in app.module.ts but I don't see anything in the console (even if I intentionally put in a wrong route). I start the app with "ng serve".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /admin doesn't redirect because it is not provided with a redirect, you're telling it to render a component.

```js
//admin-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
 {
   path: '',
   redirectTo: 'dashboard/default'
   children: [
    {
      path: 'dashboard',
      loadChildren: () => import('./theme/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
    }
  ]
},
```

Comment: That's the problem that /admin route doesn't work (doesn't redirect). Can you please write me some code so I can better understand what you mean ? Thanks.

Comment: Ohh, i misread your question. Then it all makes a lot more sense. I'll edit the answer

Comment: The component that is rendered has a router-outlet in it. And if I access /admin/dashboard/default it works fine. The problem is that when I put /admin it should redirect and give me the same page.

Comment: You're not providing a redirect, so obviously it cannot redirect. Your config makes it render the 'ProviderAdminComponent' when you go to /admin

Comment: I see your point. So there is no way I can both keep the component and redirect the /admin ?

Comment: Because if I ditch the component, I won't have the route /admin/dashboard/default accessible anymore. I guess I have found a limitation of Angular. If you specify component it won't allow you to redirect the '' route. I am using Angular 11.

Comment: Sounds like wrong design to me. There is not need for a component for a route that always redirects. The component should be on the route that will render it

Comment: It doesn't always redirect. I have /admin/dashboard/default, and will have /admin/auth/login, etc. I just wanted /admin to be a shortcut to /admin/dashboard/default.

Comment: It DOES always redirect. You're telling the ' ' route to redirect to somewhere else which means /admin will never be active. It is physically impossible to redirect and not redirect at the same time (Schrödinger may or may not disagree). You have no need for the 'ProviderAdminComponent'

Comment: Ok, I understand that. But for example in dahsboard-routing.module.ts where I don't have a component, I can write something like:
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'default',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'default',
        loadChildren: () => import('./default/default.module').then(m => m.DefaultModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'ecommerce',
        loadChildren: () => import('./ecommerce/ecommerce.module').then(m => m.EcommerceModule)
      },
...

Comment: And there /admin/dashboard is a shortcut for /admin/dashboard/default, even though I have there also /admin/dashboard/ecommerce which is also accessible.

Comment: Then you need to change your design, obviously.